# Implementing the left slide menu in navigation

Tags: java, android

I would like to implement a similar structure like below image in my navigation layout with a list of options to choose.

[image]

Right now, I have a expandable list view with a dropdown list in my navigation layout as follows:

[image]

My question is

1. What does the first slide menu called, so that I can do my research and implement the menu. 
   Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need an 3rd library or custom implementation to work you
For example check this

https://github.com/JingYeoh/SlideMenuLayout

or check on Github for favoured library

Comment: Or check website like Android Arsenal

Comment: Isnt anything available in android without 3 party library. Something similar to `expandablelistView`

Comment: @cantona_7 The implement for yourself and add it as module dependency in project. That how you can do it.